# Reusing methods in different activities in Android

Tags: android, methods, android-activity, reusability

Is it possible to reuse methods in different activities? Say for example, I have `retrieveAllStudents()` in `StudentActivity`. Can I make it static or something and call the method in `ClassActivity`? Or do I need to duplicate the method in both activities?

Which one is correct?

Example 1:

StudentActivity

```
public static ArrayList<Student> retrieveAllStudents(){
    ...
    return studentList;
}
```

ClassActivity

```
import StudentActivity

ArrayList<Student> studentList= StudentActivity.retrieveAllStudents();
```

Example 2:

StudentActivity

```
public static ArrayList<Student> retrieveAllStudents(){
    ...
    return studentList;
}
```

ClassActivity

```
public static ArrayList<Student> retrieveAllStudents(){
    ...
    return studentList;
}

ArrayList<Student> studentList= retrieveAllStudents();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is `public static` it is definitely accesible from other activities (and any other class in your app).  However, when activities call functions on each other, it can lead to overly complex code.  Consider moving the getStudent() function and other shared functionality to a separate Student class.

**Edit**  yes it is possible to reuse methods in other classes.  This is very common and considered a best practice.  Given your two examples, the first is more correct.

Comment: If previous will be killed,will there be any problem of accessing it's function?

Comment: @AndroidPower  No.  Calling a static method on a class does not require that the class be instantiated.  If it is an instance method, then the class does need to be instantiated but an instantiated class is very different from the Activity lifecyle.

Comment: Ok. If I understand correctly, if the method is in a `class`, there is no problem. However, what if the static method is in an `Activity`?

Comment: @spatulamania That i am asking.If activity is finished then it's destroy method will be called.So let's say activity1 has one static method getName(),so can i call activity2.getName() ?

Comment: @ZXingIT `Activity` is a class

Comment: Usually in Java applications, we have the MVC model where we will reuse the methods by calling the controllers. In this case, `getStudent()` can be in the `Student` class, but what about other methods such as `retreiveAllStudents()`?

Comment: @AndroidPower I don't think I understand your question.  If an activity is finished, that has nothing to do with being able to call a function on it.  Is there a specific problem you're having?

Comment: @spatulamania Yup, so I will need to import that Activity and like what AndroidPower said, we use `StudentActivity.getStudent()`? I am not sure how the Android structure of reusing methods can be implemented as there are no specific way to implement controllers.

Comment: Added examples to my question

Comment: @spatulamania Your method is correct but I would like to know what you think of the one suggested by Zoombie. I did a search and it also seems correct. Which is the correct way of reusing methods? Or are both methods suggested correct?

Comment: all ways of sharing code can be 'correct' based on your specific requirements.  Zoombie suggests putting a static function on the Application class.  I think this is a bad place to share code since the Application class already has a purpose.  From what I understand of your code, the ideal place would be a **new** class that could contain this code and be accessible from both the `StudentActivity` and `ClassActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a generic method, then keep it in Application class, make static context of application class

`public static Context getAppContext() {
        return context;
    };`

Answer (score 0):

By my opinion better approach would be to make class (just class but not Activity) with necessary methods, then create instance of that common methods class in Activity and use methods when u need them. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9414220/304270))

Other solution would be to extend StudentActivity from ClassActivity if they both need to be Activities which is not the case here.

Anyway maybe you should think again what classes should be Activities in your App.
It might be useful to read a bit about [activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html). 
Then I propose using one of two methods described above according to your needs. That will prevent problems caused by removing your activity from stack by Android system (you can read about activity [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle) too) .

Cheers