# Crash when calling methods from another class

Tags: android, methods, helper

In order to reduce redundant code among different activities I'm trying to define a helper class with shared methods and call it when I need, as I read, for example, [Calling methods from other classes in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118029/calling-methods-from-other-classes-in-android/) here. Still can't make it work. What's wrong with this code?

helper.class (I set a custom view for the action bar and define the up intent)

```
public class helper extends Activity {


public void loadActionBar(ActionBar ab, int icon, int t) { 
    ab.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar); 
    View v = ab.getCustomView();         

    TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ab_title); 
    title.setText(getText(t)); 

    ImageView logo = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ab_logo);
    logo.setImageResource(icon);

    logo.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onClick(View v) {
                                     Intent i = getParentActivityIntent();
                                     startActivity(i); }
                             }
    );

    ab.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    ab.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
}
}
```

a1.class (my activity)

```
public class a1 extends helper { 

private helper helper = new helper();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a1);

    helper.loadActionBar(getActionBar(), R.drawable.action_back, R.string.title_a1);
}
}
```

I'm passing all the relevant code. Method loadActionBar used to work when it was in class a1 extending Activity.
Here's what I get:

```
11-27 20:19:59.662    7618-7618/com.tinix.prova1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tinix.prova1/com.tinix.prova1.a1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
        at android.content.Context.getText(Context.java:323)
        at com.tinix.prova1.helper.loadActionBar(helper.java:21)
        at com.tinix.prova1.a1.onCreate(a1.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try making your method `static`

Comment: I can't since it has non-static methods in it (getText for example)

Comment: Name your classes with PascalCase rule ("Helper" instead of "helper").  have you declared the activity in the manifest file?!

Comment: Declared a1 of course, should I do the same with Helper?

Comment: Which line is 21 in your loadActionBar method?

Comment: title.setText(getText(t)); I'm sure t is ok. "title" might be null but I can't figure out why. The issue looks helper-related, because the method works fine if pasted in a1.

Comment: Man please debug your app. Set a breakpoint at line 21 and debug and look what in line 21 is null. And if you know that then remove breakpoint and start debug again and step trough debugging and look why this is null. ;-)

Comment: Title can just be null if you don't inflate the layout where the view you are referencing too is. If you don't inflate the layout correctly then title will be null!

Comment: @m iav, read my answer and tell if it help you.

Comment: And please use @[my user name] to notify me me. If you don't do that i don't know if you got update for me :)

Comment: @Mike thank you ;) I got your debug instructions, but I'm not very confident about reading the results. I'll read more about debugging and then try again. Now I solved the problem as I just wrote. Still don't know why "title" was being null. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my own problem.

It works fine by not explicitly recalling the Helper class in the main activity - neither with `private Helper helper = new Helper();`, nor when calling the methods stored in Helper.

For instance, in my onCreate I just call `loadActionBar` - instead of `Helper.loadActionBar`.
It looks quite obvious to me now, since my activity actually `extends` the Helper class.

Nonetheless I don't know why I was detecting the null issue on `title.setText(getText(t));`. I can't see any relation with that.
If someone could provide an answer this would be a bit more useful for other users. I'll wait some time before accepting this answer.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it actually solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your exception is:

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.tinix.prova1/com.tinix.prova1.a1}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

be sure to have inside your layout : `R.layout.custom_actionbar`
a `TextView` with id `ab_title`

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/ab_title"
```

title is null here:

```
title.setText(getText(t));
```